# Using php's SimpleXMLItterator to print sub elements in order

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am dealing with the following XML:

```
<Paragraph>This is a test. This is a test.
<Italic>This is an italicized test</Italic>
This is more tests
 </Paragraph>
```

I'm trying to pull in the XML, modify it as a text string or HTML code, and spit it back out. I'm running into the issue that I see no way of keeping all this text in its correct order. This is my code:

```
$xml = "<Paragraph>This is a test. This is a test.
<Italic>This is an italicized test</Italic>
This is more tests
 </Paragraph>";
$itterator = new SimpleXmlIterator($xml);
$non_italicized = $itterator->__toString();
for ($itterator->rewind(); $itterator->valid(); $itterator->next()) {
  $italicized = $itterator->current()->__toString();
}
```

The output of $non_italicized:

```
 This is a test. This is a test.
 This is more tests
```

The output of $italicized:

```
This is an italisized test
```

This leaves me no real of way of combinging them together in a regular paragraph with italicized text in the middle. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with DOM:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);

foreach ($doc->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes as $i) {
    echo "Element is: " . $i->nodeName . " Value is: " . trim($i->nodeValue) . "\n";
}
```

The output will be:

```
Element is: #text Value is: This is a test. This is a test.
Element is: Italic Value is: This is an italicized test
Element is: #text Value is: This is more tests
```

However, it will be easier if the regular text is enclosed in some tags.

Comment: Is there really no way of doing this normally with SimpleXMLItterrator? This is not my XML, but I did run it through a validator and its valid XML. I'm already using SimpleXMLItterator and don't want to have two separate iterators.

Comment: SimpleXML does not see them as separate text nodes - you can use directly `echo simplexml_load_string($xml)->__toString();` and see that the entire text enclosing `<Italic>` is displayed. SimpleXML is basically what it says it is - simple. DOM is much more advanced.